# How to use alt codes in github's new issue page

Tags: github, markdown

I have a need to provide the `left arrow key symbol` in a github issue.

I found [alt code 27](https://fsymbols.com/keyboard/windows/alt-codes/list/shortcuts/) that could help, but have no idea how to use this on github's markdown.

Is there a way to provide the same?

If not, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - use the `&larr;` HTML entity to produce a left arrow (←).

[See other HTML entities here.](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp)